# Equal height and window resize function on EACH element of the multiple CSS classes

Tags: javascript

Not an expert on coding, find a solution on how to use "each". But then suck on combining with the equal heigh line. Please help!
After everything load, "slick-list" is the one that equal with the height of the tallest slide. Then I want that/ each "carousel-wrap-x band" equal on it own "slick-list".

```js
$("[class*='carousel-wrap-'] .carousel").each(function() {
  $(this).slick({
  appendArrows: $(this).siblings('.carousel-control'),
  other functions
  });

  $(this).siblings({
  var offsetHeight = $(this).siblings('.slick-list').outerHeight();
  $(this).siblings('.carousel .band').outerHeight(offsetHeight);

  $( window ).resize(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.carousel .band').css("height", "100%")
    var offsetHeight = $(this).siblings('.slick-list').outerHeight();
    $(this).siblings('.carousel .band').outerHeight(offsetHeight);
  });

  });


});
```

```html
<div class="carousel-wrap-1">
<div class="carousel-control"></div>
<div class="carousel">
<div class="slick-list">
<div class="band">1</div>
<div class="band">2</div>
<div class="band">3</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I totally understand what you're going for - definitely a lot going wrong here, I applaud your adventurousness if you're relatively new to code though!  I'm familiar with both slick slider and jquery's "each" - so here are a few things I see going wrong.

The jquery function .each() takes in two parameters - index and element.  I think index is the index of the array you'd get back from $("[class*='carousel-wrap-'] .carousel") - I don't generally use that - and element is the element returned by the selector, sans jquery wrappage.

I can't remember what "this" is going to refer to but looking in my own code I'd be using the $(element) in its place
e.g.

```
$(".selector").each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).addClass("do-a-thing");
});
```

As for this bit - $(this).siblings( {... } );
First off, siblings takes in a selector - I'm guessing that passing in a block of code like that just blows it up?

Second, the containing .each()'s parent selector is for "[class*='carousel-wrap-'] .carousel" - so that'd look for the siblings of the carousel, which is just carousel-control, which is clearly not what you're looking for.

Lastly, the window event listener - if you want that to apply to a specific object, I believe you'll need .bind(this) (or .bind($(element)) or whatever) after the function call like so:

```
  $( window ).resize(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.carousel .band').css("height", "100%")
    var offsetHeight = $(this).siblings('.slick-list').outerHeight();
    $(this).siblings('.carousel .band').outerHeight(offsetHeight);
  }.bind(this));
```

Otherwise I think "this" will be the window

Still not 100% on what you're trying to do - educated guess, you're trying to make the bands inside slick list equal height, and slick-list is a carousel slide (so it's a slide with 3 columns or somesuch)?

If that's the case, have you tried experimenting with making it a flex box?  Could be a problem you could solve with CSS instead of javascript, and that's always preferable!

Good luck and I hope that helps!